# What is the command to modify the record data of an existing DNS A record through Windows PowerShell? Error when using Set-DnsServerResourceRecord

Tags: powershell, dns, command, subdomain, a-records

*What is wrong with this command?*

**Set-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "xxyzz.com" -Name "Testrecord" -A -IPv4Address "175.18.13.23"**

*Error below*

> > Set-DnsServerResourceRecord : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Name'.
> > At line:1 char:56 + Set-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "xxyzz.com" -Name "Testrec ...+                                                     ~~~~~+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-DnsServerResourceRecord], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Set-DnsServerResourceRecord

*I was able to find the right PowerShell command myself - For people who may need this*

```
### Start Variables ###
$DNSName = "Testrecord"
$DNSZoneName = "YourDomain.com"
$IPAddress = "175.18.13.23"
### End Variables ###

$oldobj = get-dnsserverresourcerecord -name $DNSName -zonename $DNSZoneName -rrtype "A"
$newobj = get-dnsserverresourcerecord -name $DNSName -zonename $DNSZoneName -rrtype "A"
$newobj.recorddata.ipv4address=[System.Net.IPAddress]::parse($IPAddress)
Set-dnsserverresourcerecord -newinputobject $newobj -oldinputobject $oldobj -zonename $DNSZoneName -passthru
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for ```Set-DnsServerResourceRecord```? If it’s this one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/set-dnsserverresourcerecord?view=windowsserver2022-ps - then most of your parameters don’t exist.if you’re trying to *add* an ```A``` record have a read of ```Set-DnsServerResourceRecordA``` (note the “A” on the end of the cmdlet name) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/add-dnsserverresourcerecorda?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: To change a existing record I’d look at reading it first with ```Get-DnsServerResourceRecord```, changing the properties and then passing the object back to ```Set-DnsServerResourceRecord```.

Comment: @mclayton It is the same documentation. Can you give an example? I did change the parameter from "Name" to "HostName" That did not help. I am looking to modify only the record data, that is the IP address of the Host A record.